# How to include htop in buildroot

Tags: python, buildroot, htop

I'am using buildroot but it looks like the depencies for the htop package are wrong.
I've selected htop and host-python but when building buildroot will try to compile htop first and stops with the following error:

```
>>> htop 2.2.0 Building
PATH="/home/azagent/a1/_work/6/s/buildroot-2020.02.6/output/host/bin:/home/azagent/a1/_work/6/s/buildroot-2020.02.6/output/host/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"  /usr/bin/make -j7  -C /home/azagent/a1/_work/6/s/buildroot-2020.02.6/output/build/htop-2.2.0/
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/azagent/a1/_work/6/s/buildroot-2020.02.6/output/build/htop-2.2.0'
./scripts/MakeHeader.py CategoriesPanel.c
./scripts/MakeHeader.py MainPanel.c
./scripts/MakeHeader.py DisplayOptionsPanel.c
./scripts/MakeHeader.py Header.c
./scripts/MakeHeader.py htop.c
./scripts/MakeHeader.py ProcessList.c
/usr/bin/env: /usr/bin/env: ‘python’‘python’: No such file or directory
: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
```

If i'am building without htop first and then rebuild with htop selected again, everthing work fine.
Does anyone else has this problem and knows how to fix it?
Do i need to patch the htop package dependencies?

Comment: Works here on Buildroot git master with an ARM32 defconfig. Can you post your defconfig and Buildroot version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment i solved it by myself by installing python on my host machine.